# dompdf margin after page break

Tags: css, dompdf

I've created a pdf from dompdf that includes several elements, depending on what my users choose.  I don't want it to break within an element, so I have used the page-break-inside: avoid tag in css.

It works just fine, but it also adds additional margin to the element that avoids the page break.  It seems to match the bottom margin of the page.  There is a lot of code that goes in to producing these elements, so instead of trying to post all of it I wanted to see if anyone knows if the page-break is supposed to add a margin or not.

Thanks!

Comment: This does sound familiar, though it's easier to identify the issue with some sample HTML. Is the additional margin on top or bottom? Using tables? Latest version of dompdf? This issue could be related: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/590

Comment: Thank you!  Turns out that was the issue, I updated dompdf and the strange spacing went away.

Comment: Same problem here. :(